# Incompatible peer dependency (using ng update @angular/core) - clarifying message

Tags: angular, npm

I am updating my Angular project to `11.0.5` by running the command below:

`ng update @angular/core@11.0.5`

An error message that comes is as follows:

`Package "codelyzer" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires ">=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0" (extended), would install "11.0.5")`

Questions:

1. *If* Angular were to be updated to `11.0.5`, does this mean the existing codelyzer will not run as it is only compatible with Angular within this version bracket: >=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0?
2. How do I interpret "would install 11.0.5"? Does it mean by running the command `ng update @angular/core@11.0.5`, this will update Angular to 11.0.5, of which the consequences are it will be incompatible with the existing version of codelyzer?
3. In most SO cases, people have suggested running the update with the `--force` flag. Is the correct way to update codelyzer first? Then only update Angular to `11.0.5`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular has deprecated the use of `Codelyzer`

> We’re deprecating the use of TSLint and Codelyzer in version 11. This means that in future versions the default implementation for linting Angular projects will not be available. The `ng lint` command will function similarly to `ng deploy`, suggesting recommended implementations developers could add to their projects.

So basically Angular is recommending the use of `eslint`. If you have upgraded to angular 11 then I suggest that you also migrate to using `eslint` by following [the steps in the official Angular documentation](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint#migrating-from-codelyzer-and-tslint)

> If Angular were to be updated to 11.0.5, does this mean the existing codelyzer will not run as it is only compatible with Angular within this version bracket: >=2.3.1 <7.0.0 || >6.0.0-beta <7.0.0?

If you install with `--force` flag `codelyzer` will run. But the major problem is that in future versions of Angular as this is being deprecated, this will be removed so better to upgrade as recommended

> How do I interpret "would install 11.0.5"? Does it mean by running the command `ng update @angular/core@11.0.5`, this will update Angular to 11.0.5, of which the consequences are it will be incompatible with the existing version of codelyzer?

Yes, this will update several versions of dependencies to `Angular 11.0.5`. I did update my project to Angular 11 using the `--force` flag but didn't experience any difference in how `codelyzer` worked.

> In most SO cases, people have suggested running the update with the --force flag. Is the correct way to update codelyzer first? Then only update Angular to 11.0.5?

If you need to update then due to the incompatible dependencies, without the `--force` flag then the command will fail. You can use the `--force` flag and after a successful install update resolve the warnings raised like migrating from `tslint` to `eslint`